# Terraform - Azure Load Balancer Rule - Referencing frontend IP

Tags: azure, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Could you please help with pointing me in the right direction? I am unable to reference the name of my frontend ip configuration, from my  load balancer resource, to my load balancer rule resource.

I have read the documentation and reference the front end ip configuration name in the load balancer rule via the exported `front_ip_configuration` name. In addition to also trying just copying the name of the public IP name in the load balancer rule resource.

#### Please see the below `load-balancer.tf` config file

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "internal_lb_public_ip" {
  name                = "PublicIPForLB"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

# internal standard sku load balancer 
resource "azurerm_lb" "internal_lb" {
  name                = "myIntLoadBalancer"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "LoadBalancerFrontEndIP"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.internal_lb_public_ip.id
  }

  tags = local.common_tags
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------

# backend address pool - defines the group of resources that will serve traffic for a given load-balancing rule.
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "backend_pool" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.internal_lb.id
  name            = "myBackendPool"
}

# addresses of vms placed within backend address pool.
# note: "backend Addresses can only be added to a Standard SKU Load Balancer."
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "backend_address" {
  count                   = 3
  name                    = "vmIP${count.index}"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool.id
  # private ip address taken from virtual machine network interface asssociated with virtual machine 
  ip_address         = azurerm_network_interface.vm_nic[count.index].private_ip_address
  virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.lbvnet.id
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------

# health probe 
resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "lb_http_health_probe" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.internal_lb.id
  name            = "HTTPHealthProbe"
  protocol        = "Http"
  port            = 80
  # URI, uniform resource identifier, used for requesting health status from the backend endpoint 
  request_path = "/"
  # time gap between health probes
  interval_in_seconds = 15
  # number of failed probe attempts after which the backend endpoint is removed from rotation 
  number_of_probes = 2
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------

# laod balancing rule defining how traffic is distributed to the VMs
# azure load balancer resources require the Load Balancer needs to have a FrontEnd IP Configuration Attached
resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.internal_lb.id
  name            = "myHTTPRule"
  protocol        = "Tcp"
  frontend_port   = 80
  backend_port    = 80
  # name of the frontend IP configuration to which the rule is associated.
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "${azurerm_lb.internal_lb.frontend_ip_configuration[0].id}"
  #  idle timeout in minutes for TCP connections.
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 15
  # reference to a Backend Address Pool over which this Load Balancing Rule operates.
  backend_address_pool_ids = ["${azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.backend_pool.id}"]
  # a "floating” IP is reassigned to a secondary server in case the primary server fails
  enable_floating_ip = false
  # the load balancing distribution type to be used by the Load Balancer
  load_distribution = "None"
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Please see the below debug outpt:

```
│ Error: expanding Load Balancer Rule: [ERROR] Cannot find FrontEnd IP Configuration with the name /subscriptions/00000000-00000-00000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/-----/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/myIntLoadBalancer/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEndIP        
│
│   with azurerm_lb_rule.lb_rule,│   on load-balancer.tf line 63, in resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule":
│   63: resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "lb_rule" {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
frontend_ip_configuration_name = azurerm_lb.internal_lb.frontend_ip_configuration[0].name
```